# How to write flexible and generic javascript module or plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a javascript/jquery plugin so that it is generic enough to be used in any framework such as angularjs, backbonejs, ember etc. I should be generic enough so that it should use directives if it is used with angular and backbone native functionality when it is used with backbone. Is it possible if yes then could someone guide me how?

Comment: Without knowing what your plugin does how are we meant to advise you how to make it generic?

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way I can think of is just to write it in vanilla JS. That will make it work in every framework without needing to worry about it.

If you want to go ahead with this route though, I'd use a driver-style implementation where you pipe everything to a specific driver for a particular framework. You'd define every method you want for each Driver, then the calls get forwarded on automatically to the correct Driver.

```
var myPlugin;

(function() {
   myPlugin = function(framework) {
        var me = {},
            framework = framework || 'angular';

        me.frameworks = {
            angular: new AngularDriver,
            backbone: new BackboneDriver,
            ember: new EmberDriver
        };

        // Call a method framework-agnostically
        me.fire = function(method, args) {
            if (!me.frameworks.hasOwnProperty(framework)) {
                console.log('Error: Framework not recognised.');
                return;
            }

            if (!me.frameworks[framework].hasOwnProperty(method)) {
                console.log('Error: Method not found in ' + framework + '.');
                return;
            }

            me.frameworks[framework][method].apply(this, args);
        }

        return me;
    }

    function AngularDriver() {
        var me = {};

        me.test = function() {
            console.log('Hello from the Angular Driver');
        }

        return me;
    }

    function BackboneDriver() {
        var me = {};

        me.test = function() {
            console.log('Hello from the Backbone Driver');
        }

        return me;
    }

    function EmberDriver() {
        var me = {};

        me.test = function(arg) {
            console.log('Hello from the ' + arg + ' Ember Driver');
        }

        return me;
    }
})();

var instance = new myPlugin();
instance.fire('test');
instance = new myPlugin('ember');
instance.fire('test', ['best']);
```

It's entirely possible that there's a slightly cleaner way to implement the `myPlugin.fire` function, if anyone else can improve that bit so the syntax of `instance.fire('test', ['best'])` is a bit cleaner, feel free :-)